# I need help to create a 3D model in a browser, with THREE.js . I watch a lot of tutorial but i have always white screen

Tags: three.js, 3d

I need help to create a 3D model in a browser, with THREE . I watch a lot of tutorial but i have always white screen.

This is only the load. I cannot load my file: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/hoodie-97611a53e3b846f69e0655b210f72b2f

if someone can help me or sharing me a code that can function and show me the model

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.